# How to work with subscribed observable elsewhere?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have a detail page. I am subscribing to an Observable from http get the result is assigned to an object. The page is covered with information.
Later, I want to send command to the server with http post. The post is expecting response from the server. 
I want to add data from response to the object.

**UPDATED**

Methods in service for getting and posting. Both of them are working.

```js
/* Getting the detail of the device */
getDevice(id: string): Observable<DeviceDetail> {
        const url = `${this.devicesUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get<DeviceDetail>(url)
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.log(`Fetched device id=${id}`)),
                catchError(this.handleError<DeviceDetail>(`Fetching device id=${id}`))
            );
    }

/* making action */
post(device: Device, action): : Observable<HttpResponse<Device>> {
        const url = `${this.devicesUrl}/${device.id}`;

        return this.http.post<Device>(url, action, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }), observe: 'response'
        })
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.log(`Command post successfully`)),
                catchError(this.handleError<HttpResponse<Device>>('Post command'))
            );
    }
```

The intended result is to show a detail. (working)

```js
private device: DeviceDetail;

ngOnInit() {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.deviceService.getDevice(id).subscribe((res) => {
            this.device = res;
        });
    }
```

Then click a button on the page. (working)

```html
<ion-col *ngIf="device">
<ion-button expand="block" (click)="makeAction(device)">Turn on</ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

After it sends a command and it gets the response.

```js
makeAction(device: DeviceDetail) {
        this.deviceService.makeAction(device)
            .subscribe((res) => {
                if (device) {
                    this.device.values.timeStamp.push(res['body.values.timeStamp']);
                    // I can see the response
                    console.log(res);
                    // How to add response to the object? This is not working
                     this.device.values.value.push(...res.body.values.value, ...this.device.values.value);
                   // Neither this
                   //this.device.values.value = [...this.device.values.value, ...res['body.values.value']];
                }
            });
    }
```

And is added to object and showed on the page. (I don't know how to solve)

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're problem is. Are you having trouble implementing your `makeAktion` function? Show the code you have so far! You seem to know how to send a `GET` request and display the returned data (the `device` in your code). Sending a `POST` request and displaying the returned data isn't really any different. What object do you want to add the response to?

Comment: I have edited the question with more detail. The project is on the Github. The service: https://github.com/FrankMa1/smart-grid-app/blob/master/src/app/services/device.service.ts  and the component: https://github.com/FrankMa1/smart-grid-app/blob/master/src/app/device-detail/device-detail.page.ts

Comment: You should specify return types in your functions so you (and typescript) know what you're dealing with. `post(device: Device, action): Observable<HttpResponse<Device>> { return this.http.post<Device>(...) }`. You will then notice that you're trying to push an array into an array on the line `this.device.values.value.push(res.body.values.value)`. So instead concatenate the arrays, use the spread operator or do something else.

Comment: Fixed.
Would you show me how to concatenate both observable arrays together. Thank you so far.

Comment: `this.device.values.value.push(...res.body.values.value)`

Comment: I have tried to concatenate the arrays using spread, but the same result (**Undefined**) appears same as with push.

Comment: What's `undefined`? Also please replace `res['body.values.value']` with `res.body.values.value` so we're sure the correct types are used.

Comment: ```ERROR TypeError: "deviceResponse.body.values.timeStamp.concat is not a function"```

Comment: What code is producing this error? You also don't need to push the same values into the array again just `this.device.values.value.push(...res.body.values.value);` is enough. And `this.device.values.timeStamp.push(...res.body.values.timeStamp);`

Comment: With ```this.device.values.value.push(...res.body.values.value);``` this error occures

```ERROR TypeError: "second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array"```

Comment: There's no way to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing more code. Please update your code here or update your github or create a stackblitz! Also have a look at the code here https://stackblitz.com/github/xorimqjr

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qtvsxl

Comment: Mentioned in the answer below the working code is ```this.device.values.value = this.device.values.value.concat(res.body.values.value);``` Thank you @fridoo for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the desired result.

ngOnInit is the same

```js
private device: DeviceDetail;

ngOnInit() {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.deviceService.getDevice(id).subscribe((res: DeviceDetail) => {
             this.device = res;
        });
}
```

Wrong but working.
It takes the content of the array. it adds the content to the same array plus the response.

```js
this.device.values.value.push( ...this.device.values.value, ...res.body.values.value);
```

---

### Correct way to push to the array.

It only adds the new content from the response to the object array.

```js
makeAction(device: DeviceDetail) {
        this.deviceService.makeAction(device)
            .subscribe((res) => {
                    this.device.values.value = this.device.values.value.concat(res.body.values.value);
            });
    }
```

Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Use services!!

Create a data service which will hold the data response you get from `this.deviceService.getDevice(id)`. Bind that data from the service into your html where you want to show the details.

Now when you make the post request, fetch the data from the service and append whatever new response you receive to the same data from the service.

Pseudo code.

*data.service.ts*

```
export class DataService {
    myData:any;
}
```

*details.component.ts*

```
export class DetailsComponent {
   constructor(public dataService: DataService){}
}
```

*details.component.html*

```
{{dataService.myData}}
```

*postData.component.ts*

```
export class PostData {
   constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}
   postData() {
   apiCall().subscribe(data => //udpate this.dataService.myData);
   }
}
```

*postData.component.html*

```
<button (click)="postData()">Post Data</button>
```

So on this lines. You can try to implement.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly.
Currently I have a service which is taking care of an api.
Then I am subscribing to it in the component. 
Do you mean I should create some data service which subscribe to the api service and then somehow combine the post and get together? Still I don't know how.

Comment: You can see the current thing. My service: https://github.com/FrankMa1/smart-grid-app/blob/master/src/app/services/device.service.ts  and my page https://github.com/FrankMa1/smart-grid-app/blob/master/src/app/device-detail/device-detail.page.ts

Comment: @FrankMa services can work for other services as a middle man. In my scenario one service does all of the API handling and the other service subscribes to the GET request. This allows for global variables to be used in other pages from the imported service. Of course for POST requests the API service can be called directly because the data needed is on the page already from the stored data.